# php get variables

Tags: php, get

I'm new to php and need some help with "GET" variables.

Here an extraction of my Code for index.php:

```
$array = array("section","view","sub","cat","point");
$i = 0;
$check = true;

foreach ($_GET as $position => $wert) {
  if ($position != $array[$i]) {
    //if GET doesnt exist in the array set check to false
    $check = false;
    break;
  }
  $i++;
}

//if GET variables exists
if ($check == true) {
  if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $_GET['sub'], $_GET['cat'], $_GET['point'], $point[$_GET['point']])) {
    $path = $path_dynamic.$_GET['section']."/".$_GET['view']."/".$_GET['sub']."/".$_GET['cat']."/".$point[$_GET['point']];
    check($path);
  } else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $_GET['sub'], $_GET['cat'], $cat[$_GET['cat']])) {
    $path = $path_dynamic.$_GET['section']."/".$_GET['view']."/".$_GET['sub']."/".$cat[$_GET['cat']];
    check($path);
  } else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $_GET['sub'], $sub[$_GET['sub']])) {
    $path = $path_dynamic.$_GET['section']."/".$_GET['view']."/".$sub[$_GET['sub']];
    check($path);
  } else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $view[$_GET['view']])) {
    $path = $path_dynamic.$_GET['section']."/".$view[$_GET['view']];
    check($path);
  } else if (isset($_GET['section'], $section[$_GET['section']])) {
    $path = $path_dynamic.$section[$_GET['section']];
    check($path);
    //if section isn't set
  } else if (!isset($_GET['section'])) {
    include ($path_dynamic.$section['news']);
  }
} else {
  echo "GET doesn't exist";
  include ($path_static.$section['error']);
}

//check if GET exists
function check($path) {
  if (file_exists($path)) {
    echo "File imported<br />";
    include ($path);
  } else {
    echo "GET set correct but file doens't exist";
    include ('include/static/fehler.html');
  }
}
```

Example of section.php (view, sub, cat and point is the same):

```
$section = array();
$section['error'] = 'fehler.html';
```

My problem is that if i set this link:

```
index.php?section=verein&view=vorstande
```

"vorstande" doesn't exist in my view array. So the code checks for the section "verein" and include "verein". But it should give an error.

So it seems that this code

```
 } else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $view[$_GET['view']])) {
```

is ignored and it jumps to

```
  } else if (isset($_GET['section'], $section[$_GET['section']])) {
```

Also if I change my url to this:

```
index.php?section=vereine&view=vorstande
```

nothing happens. I even don't know where the code is right now.

But if I change the url to this:

```
index.php?section=vereine&view=vorstand
```

everything works fine.

So "verein" and "vorstand" is defined by me. "vereine" and "vorstande" doens't exist.

Any suggestions? Sry for comments in german. The echo only gives me a hint where the code is right now!

[Link](http://www.jkm.gtaberlin.de/HP/) to my HP:

Edit: 
- translated comments for better conversation
- deleted all "$...[$_GET['...']]" structures to show the error I will get instead.

Comment: Where do you assign the $view array? It seems like $view[$_GET['view']] should only be set if you set it somewhere. Otherwise it won't be set (as long as you don't use register globals).

Comment: I'm sure that code would enjoy being DRYed up a bit :) Also, English is the language that's used to communicate on that site, so maybe you should translate your comments.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, this is vulnerable to local file inclusion in the worst kind of ways. Russian hackers will pwn your website within 2 minutes if you put it online like that :)

Comment: @Ynhockey: Im not using register globals. My $view array is assigned at the beginning of the index.php. I created all arrays there $section, $view, $sub, $cat and $point. Im learning php fpr 2 months in my freetime and this is my first project. Im sure that there are many bad programming parts. But my site is not that important that it would get hacked by russians i think xD So any lecture for learning more about the security aspect?

Comment: Just read an article of LFI. Get the point now. Thought file_exist would help but an injected file would return true too. Switch would be possible. But the code would really mess up if I would define each value of each GET parameter (they are over 50). Any idea? And a suggestion for DRY? BTW. updated the page without each last parameter as Geroge Cummins posted. But how to get rid of the "undefined index" part now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "vorstande" doesn't exist in my view array. So the code checks for the
>   section "verein" and include "verein". But it should give an error.

By "give an error" you mean `$check = false;`?

```
} else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $view[$_GET['view']])) {
```

If in your $view the key `vorstande` does not exist, this the whole condition will evaluate to `false` and next condition will be checked:

```
} else if (isset($_GET['section'], $section[$_GET['section']])) {
```

**Edit:**

Your code:

```
else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $view[$_GET['view']])) {
    $path = $path_dynamic.$_GET['section']."/".$view[$_GET['view']];
    check($path);
}
```

Your requirement:

```
if (!isset($view[$_GET['view']]))
    check(/* something invalid to display fehler.html */ false);
```

What actually happens:

```
isset($_GET['section'])     // true
isset($_GET['view'])        // true
isset($view[$_GET['view']]) // FALSE

=> isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $view[$_GET['view']]) // FALSE
```

If the `$_GET['view']` does not exist in `$view`, the block which would call `check` is **not** executed. If you want it to be executed regardless, simply remove the condition `isset($view[$_GET['view']])`:

```
else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'])) {
    $path = $path_dynamic.$_GET['section']."/".@$view[$_GET['view']]; // @ to suppress errors from accessing 
    check($path);
}
```

If you don't like this approach, work on your cases. You have one case for `section isset AND view isset AND view is valid`. The next case ignores the `view` parameter. So if your `view` parameter is not valid, your code handles it like it was not set. The requirement though is to have a case for `section isset AND view isset AND view is invalid`:

```
else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view']) && !isset($view[$_GET['view']])) {
    check(false);
}
```

This is of course pretty much redundant checking so just nest it to something like:

```
else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view']))
{
     // section and view have been passed

     if (isset($view[$_GET['view']])
         // view is actually valid
         $path = $path_dynamic.$_GET['section']."/".$view[$_GET['view']];

     else
         // view has been passed but is invalid. show fehler.html
         $path = false;

     check($path);
}
```

**Alternate Example**

If I understand you correctly, you have the following requirement: If the user passes a parameter `section`, `view`, `sub`, `cat` or `point`, you want that this value is also in your list of valid values. If it isn't, you want to display `fehler.html`.

We now first ensure that if the parameter is set, it is also valid:

```
foreach ($array as $param)
{
    // example for $param == "view":
    // !isset( $view[$_GET["view"]] )
    if (!isset( ${$param}[$_GET[$param]] ))
    {
        $check = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

We then check all your combinations of parameters and build a `$path`

```
$path = false;
if ($check)
{
    // your long if isset else if isset block where 
    // isset($_GET['view']) also implies isset($view[$_GET['view']])
    // so you don't have to check for it.

    // just set the $path variable with some string.
    // we are going to check it later
}
```

If now the initial `$check` failed or we built an invalid `$path`, display `fehler.html`

```
if ($check === false || !file_exists($path))
{
    // display fehler.html
}
else
    include($path);
```

Comment: by error I meant my own including part "fehler.html" and not the error code given by php

Comment: Added some more explanation. Nothing in there that hasn't been said already.

Comment: Added an alternate example on how to solve your problem more efficient.

Comment: Wow big thanks for your explanation. I read more about LFI. One source implements the file_exist part as a solution and another one uses switch to check if the variable exist in the array. Does file_exist only check if the source is available on my server? Or does an injected file also return true for this method?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "injected file", but `file_exists` just checks if the file `$path` exists and is accessible for the webserver.

Comment: code infection/file inclusion I meant. Niklas told me that this is worst kind of ways. For security aspect someone used file_exist. And now I am asking myself if this will prevent this issue.

Comment: You could just `preg_match("/^[a-z]$/D", $insecureUserParam)` or `preg_replace("/[^a-z]/D", "", $insecureUserParam)` to have your user input only contain characters `a-z`. This way there is no problem with injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
} else if (isset($_GET['section'], $_GET['view'], $view[$_GET['view']])) {
```

Each parameter of `isset` must be true for the statement to return true. In your example, `$_GET['section']` and `$_GET['view']` are set, but `$view[$_GET['view']]` is not, so execution continues on the next `else if` line.

To fix the problem, either set `$view[$_GET['view']]` previously, or remove that parameter.

Comment: I will also second the comments of others: The code you posted needs to be reworked to improve security and maintainability.

Comment: Can you add that to the answer itself, possibly with a short explanation of the dangers of LFI? You then got my upvote :)

Comment: If I remove the part $view[$_GET['view']] I am getting bad errors like "undefined" index. I just want to display my error page instead :>